# constructor from json schema

Tags: javascript, json, oop

Is there a way to build object constructors from  a JSON schema? I want to create a json schema associated with my application's namespace that I can edit once, and change the properties(before runtime) of my objects.

I know that you can write a pseudo classical object constructor like

```
var Note = function(input){ 
  var title = input
};
var newNote = new Note("test title");
```

Is it possible to create a similar structure from json? Such that I can write:

```
var Note = {
  "title":""
};
var newNote = new Note();
newNote.title = "test title"
```

I understand that this above is syntactically wrong, but I would like to for example have:

```
var notes = {
  "NotesList":[{
    "title":"note1",
    "content":"test content"
  }]
}
var newNote = new Note();
notes.NotesList.add(newNote);
newNote.title = "new title";
```

so that I can base all my objects and all of their children off of this object template created from my json schema. If this is not possible, can you recommend a better method?

Comment: That is actually not JSON, let alone a JSON schema, it's just Javascript code. Therefore for example the quotes are not necessary. And your code runs as is if you change `.add` to `.push`

Comment: The real purpose of the third example is to read the json from a schema file and create a class from that.

Comment: Why cannot you just use the parsed JSON directly? There is no need to have classes behind objects that just have data or are lists.

Comment: I want to use the json to create a class which I can call a constructor function on to create new instances of with those default properties.

Comment: You could consider this a design-time function and use something like a t4 template to generate the pseudo-classical version (or whatever) from the JSON schema as input.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understood your question completely. However if you wish to convert a function into JSON then yes, that's definitely possible.

All you need to do is use a JavaScript parser like [acorn](https://github.com/marijnh/acorn) which uses the [Mozilla Parser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API) to generate an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of your constructor in JSON format. For example:

```
var ast = acorn.parse(Note);
var json = JSON.stringify(ast, null, 4);
alert(json);

function Note(input) {
    var title = input;
}
```

See the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z8VRr/). The above code produces the following output:

```
{
    "type": "Program",
    "start": 0,
    "end": 47,
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "FunctionDeclaration",
            "start": 0,
            "end": 47,
            "id": {
                "type": "Identifier",
                "start": 9,
                "end": 13,
                "name": "Note"
            },
            "params": [
                {
                    "type": "Identifier",
                    "start": 14,
                    "end": 19,
                    "name": "input"
                }
            ],
            "body": {
                "type": "BlockStatement",
                "start": 21,
                "end": 47,
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "VariableDeclaration",
                        "start": 27,
                        "end": 44,
                        "declarations": [
                            {
                                "type": "VariableDeclarator",
                                "start": 31,
                                "end": 44,
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "Identifier",
                                    "start": 31,
                                    "end": 36,
                                    "name": "title"
                                },
                                "init": {
                                    "type": "Identifier",
                                    "start": 39,
                                    "end": 44,
                                    "name": "input"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "kind": "var"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can save the above AST in a JSON file and load it as and when required. You can use [escodegen](https://github.com/Constellation/escodegen) to convert the AST back to JavaScript as follows:

```
alert(escodegen.generate(ast));
```

See the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dyWWu/). You may then `eval` the generated code and use the `Note` constructor as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to what I was looking for. My ultimate goal was to make an object with arrays of children, each of which could have children etc. The object would then be used as the namespace to my entire application like:

```
var myobj = {};
```

I wanted to use JSON to specify the properties of this object, and then build constructors off of these properties like:

```
var myObj = {
"name": "genericname",
"id": "uniqueid",
"children": [
    {
        "grandchildren": [
            {
                "name": "child",
                "age": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
};
```

What I ended up doing was, building constructor functions from this, and then cloning them into my new objects so they could have these default values like this:

```
myObj.Child = function(){
  var child = myObj.children[0];
  return child;
  //this is the unmodified constructor child
};
var myObj.createChild = function(){
  var newChild = new Clone(myObj.Child());
  //do stuff to this is new child which can be modified without changing the original
  return newChild;
};
```